# Show implication of concavity or find counter example.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, convex-analysis

Consider $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}_+$, where $0\leq a\leq b$. I am interested in showing that if $f$ is concave, for any $x\in [a,b]$ and any $\lambda\in[1,b/x]$, $f(\lambda x)\leq \lambda f(x)$.

I have proved a particular case and I have ran multiple simulations and couldn't find a violation to the general condition I want to prove. **The particular case I have is the following:**

Suppose $a=0$ and $f(0)=0$. Then, for any $x\in(0,b]$ and $\lambda \in [1,b/x]$ define $\alpha=1/\lambda$ and $x'=\lambda x$. The definition of concavity implies that for any $x''\in [0,b]$,

$$f(\frac{1}{\lambda}x'+(1-\frac{1}{\lambda})x'')\geq \frac{1}{\lambda}f(x')+(1-\frac{1}{\lambda})f(x''),$$

Then, substituting $x'=\lambda x$ and using $x''=0$, $f(0)=0$, the above condition becomes
$$f(x)\geq \frac{1}{\lambda}f(\lambda x)$$

which is exactly what I want. I am trying to extend this particular-case proof to the case where $a\neq 0$ and $f(a)\neq 0$, but I am struggling to find the correct weight and change of variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated either to prove the general statement or to find a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a=1,b=2,x=1,f(x)=x-1,\lambda =1.5$ is a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

For a strictly concave counterexample, let
$$
f(x)=\sqrt{x}-\frac{3}{2}
$$
defined on the interval $[a,b]=[4,16]$.

Then using $x=4,\lambda=4$, we get
$$
f(\lambda x)
=
f(16)
=
\frac{5}{2}
 >
2
=
4f(4)
=
\lambda f(x)
$$